# Determine how to uncompress an archive based on the file command

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Im new to bash scripting, and I want to write a script called unpack, something like this:

```
unpack [-r] [-v] file [file...]
-v - verbose
-r - recursive - will traverse contents of folders recursively, performing unpack on each.
```

I need to determine what kind of compression was used and perform unpacking for those compression types.

Assuming file names and extensions could have no meaning - the only way to know what method to use is through the `file` command.
I have 4 unpacking options `gunzip, bunzip2, unzip, uncompress`

so I wrote a function called `execute_unpacking`

```
exectute_unpacking(){

    for FILE in "${@}"
    do
        local FILE_TYPE=$(file "${FILE}")

        # How to get the compression type of the file?

        case "${FILE_TYPE}" in
            *bzip2) bunzip2 ${RECURSIVE} "${FILE}" ;;
            *gzip) gunzip ${RECURSIVE} "${FILE}" ;;
            *Zip) unzip ${RECURSIVE} ${FILE} ;;
            *compress) uncomprees ${RECURSIVE} ${FILE} ;;
            ?) echo "${FILE} cannot be extarcted" ;;
        esac

    done
}
```

So based on the `$(file ${FILE})` i need to check for `Zip, bzip2, compress, gzip`

Is this the correct way to do it? (i don't want to use external tools like `dtrx` )

**EDIT:**
For example if I have 4 files:

```
$(file -i archive) => archive: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
$(file -i archive.bz2) => archive.bz2: application/x-bzip2; charset=binary
$(file -i archvive.gz) =>archive.gz: application/x-gzip; charset=binary
$(file -i archive.cmpr) => archive.cmpr: application/x-compress; charset=binary
```

So i need to assign to the `FILE_TYPE` variable 4 options `gzip,compress,bzip2,txt` and then match those pattern accordingly inside of my `case` statement

Comment: Looks ok, but use the `file --mime-type` command to simplify the output to be analyzed.

Comment: There is already a tool for this job. It is `7z x file` or `7z e file`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -v
case $1 in
  *.tar)     tar xvf  "$1";;
  *.tgz)     tar zxvf "$1";;
  *.tar.gz)  tar zxvf "$1";;
  *.xz)      tar xJvf "$1";;
  *.gz)      gunzip   "$1";;
  *.zip)     unzip    "$1";;
  *.rar)     unrar x  "$1";;
  *tar.bz2)  tar xjvf "$1";;
  *.bz2)     bzip2 -d "$1";;
  *)  echo >&2 "unknow $1"
                   exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Could be enhanced using `file -i` :

```
case $(file -i "$1") in
    */x-bzip2*)    bzip2 -d "$1";;
    */gzip*)       gunzip   "$1";;
    */zip*)        unzip    "$1"";;
    */x-xz*)       tar xJvf "$1";;
    ?)             echo "File $1 cannot be extracted";;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you , but there is one caveat  - Assuming file names and extensions could have no meaning - the only way to know what method to use is through the ​file​​ command. how would you solved it?

Comment: Ok, so can you please help me understand how to accomplish this using the `file -i` command? as I mentioned im new to bash scripting. I have edited the question, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

With `file -i` as [Gilles Quenot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59479737/determine-how-to-uncompress-an-archive-based-on-the-file-command#comment105136766_59479755) suggested:

```
for file; do
  local file_type=$(file -i "$file")

  case "$file_type" in
    *application/x-bzip2*)    echo "bzip2 file found";;
    *application/gzip*)       echo "gzip file found";;
    *application/zip*)        echo "zip file found";;
    *application/x-xz*)       echo "xz file found";;
    *application/x-compress*) echo "compressed file found";;
    ?)                        echo "${file} cannot be extarcted";;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Oh, now I understand what @Gilles Quent suggested, I was thinking to perform some pattern matching to match each type inside the case statements, but it looks unnecessary. thank you!

Comment: `set -- "$(file --brief --mime-type "$filename")"; file_type="${1##*/}"` then: case with `x-bzip2)`, `gzip)`, `zip)`, `x-xz)`, `x-compress)`.